# What is the process that air conditioner (AC) performs to supply the cooling air with different temperatures?

Tags: air-conditioning

Any heat exchange system as the air conditioner (AC) depends mainly on the common refrigeration cycle: evaporator, compressor, condenser and the expansion valve. Then, what does the AC do in order to provide various temperatures for the cooled air indoors?

Specifically, if I lower the temperature of the cooling air from 20°C (68°F) to 18°C (64°F), what does the AC do to achieve this lower temperature?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a pretty good understanding of how AC works. Care to [edit] your question to be more specific about exactly what part you're confused about?

Comment: Are you referring to a temperature control on the front of the AC unit, where one can dial in 20 C (68 F) or 22 C (72 F) and the AC gets the air to that temperature?

Comment: @Triplefault Yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: @FreeMan Ok, thanks for your clarification

Comment: I have edited your question to ask what I think you're asking. If I've missed, you are free to [edit] it further yourself to clarify it. However, I'll write up an answer based on that.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for your contribution, but I haven't meant this. I think the sensors used in AC are the pieces responsible for controlling the temperature of the cooling air. I meant what the process that AC performs to supply these different temperatures?

Comment: You may find looking at the process on an H-S chart may help.

Comment: Are you sure your air conditioner isn't using "Bang-Bang" controls to switch on when it's too warm and switch off when it's too cold?  You'd hear the clunk-BZZZZZ sound when it turns on periodically. It probably runs the fan continuously to help mask the jarring sound.   If it's not bang-bang, it's a software algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Air conditioning (and heating) is controlled by a thermostat where you select the room air temperature you'd like.

The AC system, as a whole, will only put out cold air at (roughly) one temperature - very cold (hold your hand over the vent when the AC is blowing - the air is quite chilly in comparison to room temp). It relies on mixing this very cold air with the air already in the room to achieve the temperature requested by the thermostat. It does *not* put out 68°F air if you set your thermostat to 68°F. If it did, and the room air was currently at 70°F, your house would *never* get down to 68° because there are things in the house (like you) that are producing heat in addition to the house leaking cooled air to the atmosphere and absorbing heat from the sun. It has to produce *much* colder air to cool the house in a (reasonably) short period of time, overcoming all the heat sources in the house in addition to the cool air losses.

The thermostat ('stat) has a thermometer built in to it as well. The 'stat compares the actual room air temperature (from the thermometer) to the desired set point. If the actual temp is above (usually by 2°F, ~1°C), then it calls for the AC system to turn on.

The AC system will pump out *very* cold air. Usually around 25-30°F *colder* than the outside air temperature. It blows this air into the house, where it is mixed with the air already in the room, slowly cooling the overall temp of the room.

Once the overall room temp has dropped below (again, usually by 2°F) the temp requested by the 'stat, the 'stat tells the AC machinery to turn off. The temp in the room immediately (but, generally, slowly) starts to rise again until the air temp is above the set point and the whole thing starts over.

The 2°F range above and below the set point allow for [hysteresis](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hysteresis) and prevent the AC equipment from "short cycling". Short cycling will cause the machinery to freeze, preventing it from working short term (until it's defrosted) and will shorten the lifespan of the entire system. Additionally, without this 2° "dead zone", the AC system would be blowing nearly constantly, cooling the house *below* the temperature desired, slowly making it colder and colder, causing you to adjust the 'stat setting up, turning *off* the AC, allowing the house to get warmer, causing you to turn the 'stat down, turning *on* the AC... It just does all that for you instead of making you do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about short cycling. I'm in the process of implementing my own temperature controls/smart remotes. The system's existing logic should be sufficient to prevent short cycling but it's something to be aware of, especially when evaluating the success of my project

Comment: There's also the newer two-stage and variable speed compressors that can operate at different "power levels", but these are rare compared to the single speed compressor you are assuming in this answer.

Comment: Do those actually put out different air temperatures, @JPhi1618, or do they just blow _cold_ air at different speeds? I dunno, so I'm asking...

Comment: There's actually two options - you can have a multi-speed blower that can blow at full speed when cooling and then drop down to a lower speed to circulate air when the compressor isn't running.  Then there are multi-speed compressors that actually cool more or less, and they run almost continuously, but spend most of their time at a low power level.  The control schemes are pretty manufacturer specific, so you are normally locked into their proprietary thermostats and repair parts are a lot more expensive since they are less common and proprietary.  That's likely the reason they are so rare.

Comment: Not *that* rare - most (probably not all - mine are, and they are dirt-common) mini-split units are variable speed drive. They vary both compressor speed and fan speed to meet load.

Comment: Thanks, for the info, @Ecnerwal. Again, though, they still put out air that's ~25-30° below outside ambient (when working correctly) and do _not_ put out different _temperature_ air based on the desired inside setting, correct?

Comment: They do appear to alter the temperature. It's not well-documented, but one indication that they do is the difference between "cool" and "dry" modes - dry mode is working harder to make the coil colder than the dewpoint to extract more water (and it uses more power, no shock value there.) Mine spend 99% of their operating life in heat mode, though. I turn them on once or twice a month in summer for an hour or so to keep everything happy, mechanically, or rarely for a few days when it's that hot. This time of year, they run all the time, pretty much.